# Vim plugin clang_complete doesn't see *.cc files

Tags: c++, vim, clang-complete

I've installed clang_complete plugin using Vundle. Seems to work for `*.cpp` files (`:set omnifunc?` gives `ClangComplete` and autocompletion mostly works as it should), but I'm rather using `*.cc` and those the plugin seems not to recognise. (`:set omnifunc?` gives nothing)

I've tried changing `~/.vim/bundle/clang_complete/plugin/clang_complete.vim`and adding `*.cc` everywhere where file extensions are listed and then do `:PluginUpdate`, but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to use YouCompleteMe. It can free you from lots of plugins.

Comment: I don't have the possibility of rebuilding vim on the server, and it's compiled without flags necessary for YCM to work.

Comment: OK. If you find a solution, please pose your answer and accept it to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaroud. I've added:

```
  autocmd BufEnter *.cc set omnifunc=ClangComplete
  autocmd BufEnter *.cc set completefunc=ClangComplete
```

to my `.vimrc`